# Integral of $e^x(1-x)^n$

Tags: integration

$$I_n=\int_0^1 e^{x}(1-x)^n \;\text{d}x \;\;\; \text{ for } n\in \mathbb{N}$$
Evaluate $I_0$.

Can someone help me out how to do this. Am I right in saying that the integral of $e^x = e^x$?

I apologize for the Format but I still havent learned how to type so that it appears with math symbols.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Now evaluate $\int_0^1 e^x dx=[e^x|_0^1$.

Comment: Yes, $I_0 = \int_0^1 e^x dx = e^1-e^0$.

Comment: What happens to the (1-x)^n ?

Comment: for $n=0$ the term $(1-x)^n=(1-x)^0=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
I_n &= \int_0^1 e^x(1-x)^n\,dx\\
I_0&= \int_0^1 e^x(1-x)^0\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1 e^x\cdot1\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1 e^x\,dx\\
&=\left[e^x\right]_0^1\\
&=e^1-e^0\\
&=e-1
\end{align}

Comment: My pleasure @Victoria. I have never learnt calculus in my class, I learned this from Wikipedia.